# C pointer to array well-defined behavior

Tags: c

Is the return value of this function well defined *by the C standard*?

```
int foo()
{
    char buff[128];
    // This is the important line:
    if ((void*)buff == (void*)(&buff))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

What is the result of `foo`?  On `gcc` and `clang`, it will always be `1`, *but I do not think that this is guaranteed by the standard*.

Comment: Where does (size_t)buff == (size_t)(&buff) come into things?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm trying to wonder the same thing, I've read the question about 20 times but I still don't get it.

Comment: I think he meant sizeof, not (size_t).

Comment: Did he actually mean sizeof(buff) is same as sizeof(int) ? If so yeah ?

Comment: The point of `(size_t)buff == (size_t)(&buff)` is that the `buff` and `&buff` will be the *same value*. This is important, since the calls to `memset` and `memcpy` will end up as `void*`s anyway.

Comment: Maybe he only meant that a pointer to an array decays into a pointer to the first element? But why do you cast to size_t, and not to void* ?

Comment: @TravisGockel: `buff` and `&buff` are supposed to be the same value - the address of the start of the array. The only difference is that they are of different type to each other.

Comment: @travis the sizeof (buf) will be size of the array which is same as sizeof (int) and not the sizeof (&buf) which is size of the pointer. In the code I can't see sizeof (&buf).

Comment: @AusCBloke: That is my question. Are they *guaranteed* to have the same value or is that something that just happens with `gcc` and `clang`? I ask because I don't think `&buff` is "the address of the start of the array," but the address of the variable `buff`.

Comment: @TravisGockel: I think you're confusing arrays and pointers. Try your code using a `char * buff = malloc(sizeof(int))`, and the test will fail.

Comment: @TravisGockel: I see what you're saying now, I hope my answer helps. Main thing to realise is that arrays != pointers.

Comment: @TravisGockel Your question should simply read "what is `&buff`?"

Comment: @TimothyJones: I'm aware that it will fail in that case. My question is if the program I'm giving has specified behavior.

Comment: @TravisGockel: It does. wildplasser and AusCBloke have the correct answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will always return 1.

An array is a contiguously allocated non-empty set of objects with the element type - arrays are not allowed to have padding before or between elements.  It follows that a pointer to an array points at the same location as a pointer to the first element, although it has a different type.

`&buff` *is* the address of the variable `buff`.  The variable `buff` in this case is an array, so `&buff` is the address of an array - and just like the address of a `struct` variable is the same location as the address of its first member (although a different type), the address of an array variable is the same location as the address of its first member.

§6.5.9 tells us:

> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers,
>   both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning)...

In this case the *"pointer to an object"* is the pointer to the array, and the *"pointer to the subobject at its beginning"* is the pointer to the first element of the array.

In other words, it returns 1 for much the same reason that this code does:

```
int foo()
{
    struct { int a; int b; } s;

    return (void*)&s == (void*)&s.a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Are they [`buff` and `&buff`] guaranteed to have the same value or is that something that just happens with gcc and clang? I ask because I don't think &buff is "the address of the start of the array," but the address of the variable buff.

They *are* guaranteed to be the same value. In C arrays can be considered "special" in the sense that they're not pointers and the only time they're treated as such is when they're passed to a function and they *decay* to pointers.

For that reason:

```
buff == &buff && buff == &buff[0]
```

However `buff` and `&buff` are of two different types, where `&buff` is a pointer to the array (they still refer to the same spot!). You can use `sizeof` on the two to see this difference for yourself.

That is **not** the same for a pointer, which as you say will return the address of that actual pointer variable. An array also isn't a pointer to itself since in order for a pointer to point to itself, the address of that pointer would need to be stored in that pointer variable.

An array name is simply a label used by the compiler that corresponds to a contiguous block of memory. It has special properties, the above being one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: a pointer to an array decays into a pointer to the first element; so `&buff[0] == &buff`. In your case there is another thing: when used as a function argument (such as memcpy (buff, ...) ) an array *name* decays into a pointer.

For `sizeof buff`, the buff *does not* decay into a pointer. (hint: use short, or long long to test that, or a platform where sizeof (void*) != sizeof (int). )

Comment: Does it say `&buff[0] == &buff` in the standard?  I'm looking through it and can't find that.